# Site Speed: web developer toolbar shows page takes a while

Tags: performance, codeigniter, smarty, yslow, pagespeed

Been monitoring the network tab of Chrome's web developer toolbar and noticed that it seems to take a while (like a couple of seconds or so) for the page to get to the browser. The page isn't doing any heavy work, such as complex SQL queries.

Other assets such as JS, CSS, images, etc seem to be reasonable. Uncached images coming from the same server sometimes is returned to the browser faster than the HTML. I'm using CodeIgniter + Smarty.

Any ideas what I should look at to pinpoint the bottleneck? And more importantly: **what are the general strategies I can do to make HTML loading faster?** My question is specifically about the HTML (as my other resources are doing fine). Assume that the script that creates the page actually executes in a reasonable time (microseconds).

Comment: Do you have a public URL you could share for this site? If not, a screenshot of the network panel could be helpful. Based on your comments so far, I would suspect a performance problem with CodeIgniter. I've never used it, but it looks like there is a profiler option you could enable to help measure its performance.

Answer (score 0):

To get detailed performance information and waterfall charts, go to http://webpagetest.org

How do you know it's your HTML that is the issue?

Have you tried rendering the page without any other assets, no images/CSS/JS?

How big is your HTML?

Are you able to gzip / compress your HTML?

From webpagetest what is your time to first byte and time for domReady, which is when the HTML document object model is complete?

Comment: I know it's the HTML because the network tab shows the timeline for each asset. HTML is minified and compressed.

Answer (score 0):

There are a lots of things that can reduce page load time, a few bellow

**1**.add this to your `.htaccess` to enable content compression

```
<ifModule mod_gzip.c>
   mod_gzip_on Yes
   mod_gzip_dechunk Yes
   mod_gzip_item_include file \.(html?|txt|css|js|php|pl)$
   mod_gzip_item_include handler ^cgi-script$
   mod_gzip_item_include mime ^text/.*
   mod_gzip_item_include mime ^application/x-javascript.*
   mod_gzip_item_exclude mime ^image/.*
   mod_gzip_item_exclude rspheader ^Content-Encoding:.*gzip.*
 </ifModule>
```

**2**.Combine images into CSS sprites

**3**.Defer loading of JavaScript

**To know more about optimization of your page/site you can use** [**this tool**](https://developers.google.com/speed/docs/best-practices/payload#CompressImages).

As far as I'm concerned that to using of any template parser makes the execution process a little bit slower.

Comment: Hi, HTML is minified and compressed already. CSS is also minified and compressed, uses sprites, efficient selectors, etc. I don't think it's a JS issues since I'm monitoring the timeline of the assets. There seems to be a lag. I also use PageSpeed & YSlow to optimize my site, but it's the HTML timeline I'm concerned about.

Comment: Well, here is a link http://serverfault.com/questions/103479/is-page-loading-time-relevant, if you can find something new.